# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable (create a folder in the same directory)

Tags: python

I want to create a folder in the same directory, where have i gone wrong?

```
def selection():
    print "Content Profiling"
    print "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
    print " 'G', 'PG13', 'NC16', 'M18', 'R21' "
    selectionInput = raw_input("Please select your content profile")
    if selectionInput == "G":
        root = os.curdir()
        path = root+"/G"
        os.makedirs( path, 0755 );
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\guicmd.py", line 44, in <module>
    selection()
  File "C:\Python27\guicmd.py", line 38, in selection
    root = os.curdir()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`os.curdir`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.curdir) is not a function but a constant string. Just is it as a value:

```
root = os.curdir
```

While you are at it, you can improve your code by using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

```
path = os.path.join(os.curdir, "G")
os.makedirs(path, 0o755)
```

Comment: i did the correction,but why the folder is created C:\Python27 instead of C:\Python27\GUI_FYP?

Comment: sorry,i am new here :) and if i want to check if existing folder is created, "if not os.path.exists(newpath): os.makedirs(newpath)" like this?

Comment: Looks OK. You are on the right track, just read the fine documentation.

Comment: @tichodrama how do i save my desired file to the newly created file after "if not os.path.exists(path): os.makedirs(path)"